# Derivating $z(x)=y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)$

Tags: derivatives, dimensional-analysis

I have two real functions, $z$ and $y$, initially defined for discrete domain. The function $z$ is related to $y$ and to $\Delta x$ by 
$$z(x)=y(x+\Delta x)-y(x).$$

These functions are dimensioneless, but $x$ have a dimension of lenght.

Well, an author states that, making the intervals smaller, we get:

$$z(x)=y'(x)$$

However, $z$ is dimensioneless and $y'$ has dimension $[\text{lenght}]^{-1}$.

I did the calculus:
$$\dfrac{z(x)}{\Delta x}=\dfrac{y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)}{\Delta x}$$
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\dfrac{z(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\dfrac{y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)}{\Delta x}$$
$$\dfrac{z}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$

This matches the units, but does what mean $\dfrac{z}{dx}$?

Many thanks.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be very well formulated...

Comment: The functions are initially defined in a discrete domain. I've tried to explain a little better. Thank you and sorry!

Comment: The first equation implies that $z$ and $y$ have the same dimension, so if $z$ is dimensionless, $y$ is also dimensionless. Do you mean that $y'$ has dimension $[length]^{-1}$?

Comment: @Peter, now I've noticed a typo, I've fixed. I mean "$y'$ has dimension ...". Many thanks!!

Comment: This just isn't true unless $z(x)=(y(x+\Delta x -y(x))/\Delta x$ as you learned in calculus.  It seems like some kind of error in the text to me.  The expression $\frac{z}{dx}$ doesn't mean anything; don't use it.

Comment: @saulspatz, I thank you so much for return, maybe you could post as anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is differentiable and $\Delta x$ is small, then $$y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)\approx y'(x).{\Delta x}$$. This would give you $$z(x)\approx y'(x).\Delta x$$

Comment: Right... Thank you so much.